# Who is Tanis talking about has seen the white stag?

Tags: dragonlance

While the companions are running from Solace, Sturm sees a white stag, much the same way Huma did. Tanis says, "Though I have not seen the white stag myself, I have been with one who has and I have followed it, like in the old man's story." Now, Tanis is only 102 years old. The only other person I know of to have seen the stag was Huma, and that was at least a thousand years before Sturm was born. Who is this person? And are there others?

Comment: I always interpreted this to mean that Tanis was saying he had already made the decision to follow Sturm, and so he referred to in the past tense. However, I can certainly see how he might have been referring to a previous event in his life.

Comment: I always assumed he meant a previous event. I just never thought to ask.

Answer (score 2):

The person who followed the stag is unknown. However, while Tanis is only 102 years old, do not forget that he grew up among the Qualinesti elves, many of whom are vastly older (The life span of a Qualinesti can be up to 700 years).

The exact quote is:

> "I'm not sure," Tanis said. He was silent for a few moments. When he spoke, it was with obvious reluctance. "Though I have not seen the white stag myself, I have been with one who has and I have followed it, like in the old man's story." His hand absently fingered the ring of twisted ivy leaves that he wore on his left hand, his thoughts with the golden-haired elfmaiden who wept when he left Qualinesti.

While *Sturm* may have only known of Huma, the white stag seems to be a prevalent legend, and has probably appeared to more than is documented, including Qualinesti (Who revere Paladine/Draco Paladin/E'li).

Side note: There are approximately 1400 years between Huma (1028 PC - Pre Cataclysm) and the events of Dragonlance I, Dragons of Autumn Twilight (351 AC - After Cataclysm).